# ERROR 000989: Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 2)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I have a Field Calculator I am using with Python and I keep getting the above error.  Below is the screenshot of my Field Calculator I am using.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I didn't see this question before answering the other. Just not that it is "overkill" to use a code block in this particular case because you can write it in a single line. Uncheck the code block and enter "water" + str(!SubTypeCode!) + format(!OBJECTID!, '%01d')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the scope when defining your function and its arguments in the pre-logic script. An actual field cannot be within the definition of the function in the pre-logic script. See screen shot of a working field calculator function:

[image: ArcMap 10.1 Field Calculator with Pre-Logic Script Code, field to the left is the field that is being calculated (it does not have to be highlighted).]

Notice how temp is defined as an argument in the pre-logic script code and keeps its name when used inside the function. Then in the JanClass = block I use the function and define which field values I want to use.

So in your case add another argument to your function, call it objectID, and then when you call your function in the box below feed it !OBJECTID!. ***Additionally I am fairly certain that OBJECTID cannot be used in field calculator operations***. If you are trying to do an auto increment function refer to the answer given by adouxju on this question - ([How to auto increment a field in a feature class?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95249/how-to-auto-increment-a-field-in-a-feature-class)).

Comment: We must have answered at almost exactly the same time. I like the pictures so +1, it's what I said *with pictures* and a bit more depth.

Comment: Thanks for the Great answer on this James.  Great details as well.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what a is supposed to be, but let's say it's FacilityID. In your PROJECT= line (the expression line) you put `autoIncrement(!FacilityID!,!OBJECTID!)` and your code block is:

```
def autoIncrement(a,ID)
  return "water" + str(a) + format(ID,"%01d")
```

I hope that clears it up for you; there's a reference http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000 but it's a lot of reading before you get to what you want.

Comment: Nice work, Cheers!