# python syntax error in field calculator

Tags: arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000989

I'm trying to strip the last character in a string if when the string is split by spaces the last element has a length of 1. I then want to put that letter in front of the rest of the other elements.

So, if I had a value of 1st Street W, I would like to convert it to W 1st Street

I'm using this code in the "Pre-Logic Script Code" box in ArcMap field calculator:

```
def getPrefix(Street_Name):
  if len(!Street_Name!.split(" ")[-1])==1:
    !StreetName2! = !Street_Name!.split(" ")[-1] + " " + !Street_Name!.split(" ")[0:-1]
```

And in the box below that:

```
def getPrefix(!StreetName2!)
```

I'm getting an error 000989, syntax indention error, but I have everything at two spaces in cascading from calling the function. Pretty sure that's the ESRI specification for the field calculator.

Comment: You have at least 2 problems that I can see: you're defining your function twice (though the second one, on the last line, won't work), and you're telling your function to use the variable `Street_Name` but you're actually using `!Street_Name!` inside the function.

Comment: @ Dan C Am I defining it twice, or passing the variable through it and calling the function in the code block? The last line is actually ina separate box of the field calculator GUI.

Comment: @Dan C The way I understand it is that you define a function in the first block and here Street_Name is the parameter. In the second block, you call the function for the field update. In this case, !StreetName2! = def getPreFix(!StreetName2!), although I think it maybe should be def getPrefix(!Street_Name!).

Comment: This answer should help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95267/error-000989-python-syntax-error-parsing-error-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-li, or this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8695/troubleshooting-error-000989-python-syntax-error-from-arcgis-field-calculator

Comment: That did it. I just had to pass in the arguments correctly. Used this in the  prelogic--- def getPrefix(Street_Name, StreetName2):
  if len(Street_Name.split(" ")[-1])<2:
    StreetName2 = '{} {}'.format(Street_Name.split(" ")[-1],Street_Name.split(" ")[0:-1])
  return StreetName2 --- and this in the box below --- getPrefix(!Street_Name!, !StreetName2!) --- my results are not the way I want. Coming out as W [u'1st', u'Street'] instead of 'W 1st Street'.

Comment: Instead of  
`StreetName2 = '{} {}'.format(Street_Name.split(" ")[-1],Street_Name.split(" ")[0:-1])`  
Use  
`StreetName2 = '{} {}'.format(Street_Name.split(" ")[-1],' '.join(Street_Name.split(" ")[0:-1]))`  
EDIT - sorry I have no idea how to make it enter on a different space. Also, added join instead of *.

Comment: That kind of works, but I am not getting the last element. Coming out as "W 1st" Instead of "W 1st Street"

Comment: Sorry, edited to do ' '.join, try that instead.

Comment: @isamson getting a general error with ''.join