# Autonumber field that is populate when a point is created

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have a feature class called Ref_Point I need a field that creates a sequential number as points are added. Im using the feature class as a numbering tool for different jobs, so when I finish a job and clear the data I want the field to start back at number 1

Comment: can't you just add the number after the editing is done. The features seem to go into the table in the order they were digitized and you can populate a numeric field after the fact. See this similar question. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95249/how-to-auto-increment-a-field-in-a-feature-class

Comment: I have tired this but I get an error .

Comment: I dont agree that this is a duplicate.  This question deals with an auto-increment that automatically occurs when a new feature is created.  The other post deals incrementing numbers using field calculator which does not occur automatically on a create feature. just my 2 cents

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should look into the Attribute Assistant which is located here: http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/ -  You want to set up the Autonumber

[image]

Set the tool to operate "On Create" and it will find the highest number in your [number] field and populate your missing data with the next autoincremented number automatically when you create a new feature.

[image]