# Failed to Generate Incremental ID with Following Python Code in the Code Block. What's the mistake in my code?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am trying to add a field with incremental ID for a shapefile with certain feature classes. I know this can be done by using Sort tool and then use the Add Incremental ID field tool. But since I'm learning Python, and this seems like not too difficult a problem to tackle with Python, I want to use Python to handle this to enhance my Python skills.

Below is the code I put in the Code Block:

```
def letsdothis():
    rec = 0
    vStart = 1
    vDelta = 1
    if rec == 0:
        rec += vStart
    else:
        rec += vDelta
    return rec
```

And the function I use of course is letsdothis()

To show it better:

[image: ID]

My reasoning is this:

The first one will be *rec += 1*, then rec will equal 1. Then the next one, since rec != 0. it will be *(the new rec value) += 1*, which will be 2. And so on and so on.

But the results are all 1. My understanding is that for every row cell/feature class, the function will be called from scratch therefore rec will equal 0 instead hold the value that's calculated in the previous feature class/row.

Is this the problem with my code? I am very new to writing my own Python code in GIS. I've only used other's code and tweaked them to fit my purpose before so I don't know how to really do this.

[image: Rec Pass on]

If I can make rec == 1 in the first row, how shall I make that value pass on to the nest row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [def variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) related confusion that you have. Basically each and every row calculation creates an instance of your def and its `rec` value is always 0! Therefore you should control its incremental behaviour outside of the def.

The original code puts `rec` variable outside of the def and declares rec as global inside the def. Check [the first part of the answer of this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95249/auto-incrementing-field-in-feature-class-using-arcgis-desktop) out.